# Replacing a 'double' field in struct while leaving the other fields intact

Tags: matlab, struct

I am trying to replace a field in a struct with new data while leaving the rest intact.

The struct is a 1x1 struct **with 19 fields**, one of which is a 512x1 double. The relevant file is called bgh.mat, containing the Spectrum structure, which contains the Data double: bgh.Spectrum.Data

Currently I have it set to `bgh.Spectrum.Data = newData;` which does replace it, but also removes all other fields in `.Spectrum`.

How do I replace the double that is .Data (`512x1`) with a new double of `512x1`, while leaving the rest of the fields in spectrum the same?

Comment: Why does replacing Spectrum.Data remove all other fields? This is an odd behaviour. I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: `bgh.Spectrum.Data = randn(512,1);` `bgh.Spectrum.Data2 = randn(512,1);` `NewData = [1:512]';` `bgh.Spectrum.Data=NewData;` Does delete field bgh.Spectrum.Data2 and also updates bgh.Spectrum.Data. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are completely correct. That is exactly how I did it, except for one thing. I put `load('bgh.mat');` instead of `bgh = load('bgh.mat');` I corrected the issue and now it works. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I put `load('bgh.mat');` instead of `bgh = load('bgh.mat');` I corrected the issue and now it works.

I have to actually assign the file to a variable before I can call it in the way I did.